# I don't want to close socket in my multi-client for single server program

Tags: network-programming

I'm building a C socket program on CentOS 6.2 like below.

1. The Server is listening to connection request from all clients.
2. Once connection is established, clients starts send log data to single server.

The problem is all clients sends log data to the same port which makes `CLOSE_WAIT` issue when the client closes the connection.

Surfing the web, I read that I should close socket to kill 'CLOSE_WAIT' connection which means the server can't accept log data from another client socket any more.

Is there any way to kill specific session on a port? If it's not possible, Should I create multi server listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is all clients sends log data to the same port which makes CLOSE_WAIT issue when the client closes the connection.

No it doesn't. `CLOSE_WAIT` means that (i) the peer has closed his end of the connection, and (ii) the local system is waiting for the local application to do the same. It has nothing to do with 'to the same port', which is how all TCP services work.

> I read that I should close socket to kill 'CLOSE_WAIT' connection

Correct.

> which means the server can't accept log data from another client socket any more.

No it doesn't. That would happen if you closed the *listening* socket. You need to close the *accepted* socket, the one you got EOS from.

> Is there any way to kill specific session on a port?

Close the socket.

> If it's not possible, Should I create multi server listener?

Surely you have already done that?

You don't have any choice about this. If you receive end-of-stream when reading a socket, you can't read anything more from it. Ever.